# When and how should DAPI and SAPI be used?

Tags: server, bloomberg

I`m totally new to Bloomberg and using Bloomberg api in python/flask
I tried to read all the documentation provided by the windows SDK

I understand that DAPI is only for local applications using localhost and default port
but actually I am confused about the usage of SAPI Installation and usage...

---

**First**:
after installing **sapi on machine with bloomberg terminal** and letting the sapi **process up** , I will write an application by python code that import blbapi and use the sapi
should this application be on the same machine , or it can be on another machine and give it the ip and port of the sapi process and should the other machine have bloomberg terminal too?

---

**second**:
what about the **client side**, any browser which open this application should the clients have bloomberg terminal too??
**Excuse my naive question ..
Thanx in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Python application machine doesn't have to have a Bloomberg terminal installed. You will only need Bloomberg libraries installed (but not terminal) software.

You need to provide "ip of terminal pc" + "uuid" when making a connection to SAPI. 
Also, the user/terminal must be logged in.

**Check and be very careful with licensing.** You can **try** asking your account manager.

Don't take this as licensing advice, but different exchanges and data sources can have different rules around the data so it depends what data you pulling. As I understand the data pulled by a user/script is for that specific terminal owner only.
Different terminal "owners" with the same access might not be allowed to see the data pulled by other scripts/users.

Answer (score 0):

SAPI allows you to use BBG data off the machine where the user is logged in HOWEVER this data can not be viewed by anyone but the logged in user - for legal reasons rather than technical ones.

The typical use case for SAPI is there complicated calculatios (be it exotic pricing or realtime portfolio risk) is being performed that aren't practical on the desktop.

Be aware that all BBG data and calculations are tied to the user, the data can't be given to anyone else...